# Mongodb execute multiple queries in one round trip

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bulk

Is there anything like elasticsearch Multi Search API ?
the link is : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html.

consider I have multiple queries and I want to give these queries to mongo and get result in order .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is something similar in MongoDB. Using Aggregation Framework you can define multiple aggregation pipelines inside [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage.

Try:

```
db.col.save({a:1})
db.col.save({a:2})


db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            query1: [ { $match: { a:1 } }, { $project: { _id: 0 } } ],
            query2: [ { $match: { a:2 } }, { $project: { _id: 0 } } ],
        }
    }
])
```

which prints:

```
{ "query1" : [ { "a" : 1 } ], "query2" : [ { "a" : 2 } ] }
```

Using `$facet` you have to keep in mind that single BSON document can't exceed 16 MB size. More about aggregation limitations [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/)

Comment: Note that if you need to provide a hint for this query, this is possible only in MongoDB version 3.6 or later

Comment: To clarify, you might need to provide a hint, because otherwise mongo will probably not use an index, due to: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30474

Comment: Thank you @Joe for your comment